# How to check a response from an api call in python for specific data

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python code where I am making a https request.

```
        import urllib3
        https = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
```

Here is how I am making a call to an api

```
        myResponse = https.request(method="GET", url=f"{myEndpoint}?acctId={accountID}&acctType={accountType}", headers=headers)
        response = json.loads(myResponse.data.decode("UTF-8"))
```

I know that response does not contain response["Records"]

I want to have few more lines of code but will need to run those lines if response contains response["Records"]

The code below always runs because response["Records"] is not contained in the response

```
        if((response["Records"] != None) and (len(response["Records"]) != 0)): 
             pass
```

How can I write the python code to check response and only run my other lines of code if response["Records"] exit  in response?

Comment: `if response.get("Records") is not None:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict\[key\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)